# Does initializing arrays have a significant effect on C++ performance?

Tags: c++, arrays, c, performance, memory

I am trying to decompose a 4000+ line block of legacy C++ code into separate functions. At the beginning of the function, a lot of char arrays are declared. The same arrays are used in completely different ways as buffers for data, for example:

```
char array[4];
strcpy(array, "foo");
//something with foo
strcpy(array, "bar");
//something with bar
```

I want to separate these into

```
void foo() {
    char foo[4];
    strcpy(foo, "foo");
    //something with foo
}

void bar() {
    char bar[4];
    strcpy(bar, "bar");
    //something with bar
}
```

However performance is important here, and I'm wondering if initialising many more arrays is likely to negatively impact speed. (Obviously I'm not going to paste 4000 lines of code).

Comment: [Profile your application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) and find out.

Comment: That's not "legacy C++", that's C. Do you need it to remain C, and if not, have you measured that a plain `std::string` isn't fast enough?

Comment: You'll probably not lose any performance by creating different arrays as these are static arrays on the stack whose allocation is just incrementing the stack pointer. But you'll have to pay the cost of calling functions now if these are not inlined.

Comment: @Quentin It is also C++. A lot of code is valid in both languages

Comment: The comment about profiling is really the best suggestion.  It appears your example is contrived.  I highly doubt that the buffer is 4 bytes, and you have not described the "something".  It could be the buffer is shared due to cache performance considerations.  If you profile the original code and profile your changes, you'll find out whether there is a difference.

Comment: @M.M code "being" in a language means more than "doesn't make the compiler scream at you", especially if the goal is to refactor and maintain it.

Comment: Both variants should have the similar execution times. The only difference is the function calls themselfs for calling `foo` and `bar` which might be slightly slower, but this difference is certainly not significant.

Answer (score 1):

> Does initializing arrays have a significant effect on C++ performance?

One cannot make universal generalisations that would apply to all programs. But in case of small arrays: Initialisation rarely has significant cost. You can find whether the cost is significant in your program by measuring.

Default-initialising an array of trivial objects - such as in your example - has (typically) no overhead at all.